# Docker: Swarm workers connecting to server

Tags: docker, networking, server, overlay, swarm

I have a bunch of swarm containers (now in one single host, but potentially in a multihost system, conforming a multinode swarm).  The system is composed of a data server and a set of autonomous workers processing the bits received by the server and ingesting back the results.  The input data retrieval and output data ingestion is done with HTTP GET/POST.  The server side (data provision and results reception) works, and when tested against a worker running in any host, without Docker, it runs without problem.  But I need to place these workers in a Docker swarm.

What I cannot achieve is the communication between the different swarm workers and the external server.  My server is running in a host with IP 10.69.180.30, in the port 8080.

```
python test-dataserver.py -H 10.69.180.30 -p 8080
```

After digging in several forums, I tried to create an overlay network with --subnet 10.69.180.0/24, and then launch the service of workers connected to this network in another host.  But no way.

```
docker network create --driver overlay --subnet 10.69.180.0/24 mynet
docker service create --network mynet --name mysrv --replicas 4 \
                 centos curl http://10.69.180.30:8080/get_task
```

In this simple example I don't call the worker but just `curl` to the address of the server and the `get_task` node.  It should return a `JSON` string with information about the task to be executed.  But on the server side I do not get any request.

I'm not a network expert, so I might be missing something trivial...  (BTW, I first tried to do the same, but having the server running in the same host, without success.)

Do you know if this setup is possible?  I will very much appreciate any hint to make this work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i would create a overlay network with Dockers default IP Range

docker network create --driver overlay mynet

After this add the external host to the services.

```
docker service create 
       --add-host external:10.69.180.30 \
       --network mynet --name mysrv --replicas 4 \
       centos curl http://external:8080/get_task
```

Comment: But, does swarm create command allow `--add-host` option?  I thought it was only available for _traditional_ containers.  At least it does not work in my system...

Comment: Definitely, it does work!  I mean, if I modify the image so that the `/etc/hosts` file contains the IP of the server, the communication is established!  Now, I would like to achieve the same but without having to tune the image of the containers...